# Trouble storing fields in a contact information class

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to write a class that stores a person's name and number.

```python
class Contact(object)
    def __init__(self, name, number)
        self._name = name
        self._number = number

    def getNumber(self):
        return self._number

    def setNumber(self, newNumber):
        self._number = newNumber

    def numberUpdate(self):
        newNumber = number
        self.setNumber(newNumber)

    def action(self):

        person = Contact("Jonathan")

        number = input("What's your number: ")
        person.numberUpdate()

person = Contact()
Contact.action(person)
```

It prompts me for the number as I would hope. But after I enter the number, it keeps giving me this error:

```py
NameError: global name 'number' is not defined
```

Can anybody tell me what I did wrong here? I tried:

```py
 def numberUpdate(self, number):
    newNumber = number
    self.setNumber(newNumber)

def action(self):

    person = Contact("Jonathan")

    number = input("What's your number: ")
    person.numberUpdate(number)
```

and it gives me:

```py
TypeError: numberUpdate() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### General suggestions

The design of your Contact class is broken in quite a few ways (for example, the `action()` method should not be instantiating a new Contact object within the Contact class).

It looks like your Contact class is meant to store one name and a number with that name. You should not be specifying a specific name within the `action()` method, you should instead allow the class to store anybody's name. Handle the storing of a name in the `__init__` method, or with setter methods.

Also, you should really rename your `action()` method - the name gives no hint whatsover as to what its result will be. Your syntax on calling the `action()` method is wrong too.

#### Overarching problem

Basically, you're having problems because you're not understanding some of the basics of object-oriented programming. Instead of struggling through each error, I'd recommend taking some time to read up on how objects and classes work.

Comment: I understand that I should not be initiating a new instance within the object class. However, I am trying to test something here. That is why I am doing it and also inputting a name by myself. I understand the basics of it using a getter and setter method. My main objective of this is to understand how to pass a variable within each method. I would appreciate it if you can guide me here.

Comment: I'm happy to guide you, but trust me when I say there are so many errors with your code that you need a thorough re-visit of how classes work.

To "pass a variable within each method," you should probably just store the variable in a field. You can also call a method that returns a variable.

Comment: Also, to be clear, creating a Contact object with the name "Jonathan" is a perfectly valid way of testing. This just belongs _outside_ of the class.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will try and do what you suggested. Many thanks.

Comment: Hi David, I have attempted what you have said and moved my "method" into a class in another file. It works much better and is much cleaner now. Just wanted to say thank you. Cheers!